# game engine hides cursor (windows 8.1/parallels) Also a OS X 10.12.5 issue.

Tags: game-engine, installation, 3d-cursor

Just installed blender 2.78 on windows 8.1 under parallels. When I start the game engine, the cursor disappears when it enters the blender window. Crtl-alt to release the cursor doesn't help. changing the settings to optimize or not for games doesn't help.

Different problem on blender install directly on the mac (10.12.5). Here, when I start the game engine the blender window just flickers rapidly and becomes entirely unusable.

In both cases everything is fine until the game engine starts.

Any guesses?

Comment: This is expected behavior, cursor is hidden by default unless coded otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To see the mouse cursor when bge is running active **Mouse cursor checkbox** in render tab of property panel.

[image: property panel]

2. Or use a script to show the mouse cursor.

   [image: script]

You can use logic or render to show the mouse cursor while BGE is running.

1. Using [bge.logic.mouse](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_release/bge.types.SCA_PythonMouse.html#bge.types.SCA_PythonMouse)

   ```
    from bge import logic
    logic.mouse.visible = True # 1 or True are acepted, to disable 0 or Flase
   ```
2. Using [bge.render.showMouse()](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_release/bge.render.html?highlight=render%20mouse#bge.render.showMouse)

   ```
   from bge import render
   render.showMouse(1) # 1 or True are acepted, to disable 0 or False
   ```

**NOTE:** When BGE is running you are unable to make change to configurations, property, objects, scripts, etc.